# Работа со строками (string) в С++

Tags: c++, строки, c++11

Подскажите как можно сделать сие действие:

есть n-ое кол-во строк вида: 1. Какой-то текст. 2. Какой текст.

Нужно сформировать массив строк, где каждый элемент(строка) будет в виде:

1. Какой-то текст.

На С# получилось сделать легко, на С++ пока не осилил.

К примеру:

```
// Исходные данные

string str = "1. Подъем в 8 утра. 2. Подъем в 9 утра. 3.Подъем в 10 утра."

// Выходные данные - массив строк, где:

stringArray[0] == "1. Подъем в 8 утра.";
stringArray[1] == "2. Подъем в 9 утра.";
stringArray[2] == "3. Подъем в 10 утра."
```

Comment: Второй раз за сегодня пишу один и тот же комментарий: Думаю, когда вы сможете сформулировать задачу так, что ее условие поймут другие - вы и сами сможете ее решить. Пока же ее не понимаете ни вы, ни, думаю, все мы...

Comment: Хотябы покажите что вы сделали на С#(скопируйте прямо в вопрос), тогда немного легче будет ваш вопрос понять

Comment: @Harry, добавил пример.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, добавил пример.

Comment: А что делать, если `2. Завтра подъем в 3.` ?..

Comment: @Harry, текст может быть абсолютно разным, но начинается с 1., 2. и т.д. Также заканчивается точкой. И есть возможность добавить свой разделить между этими предложениями. То есть: исходная строка может принять вид:                                           
"1. Подъем в 8 утра. СВОЙ РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬ 2. Подъем в 9 утра. СВОЙ РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬ 3.Подъем в 10 утра."

Comment: ну это самый легкий вопрос:  string stringArray[] ={ str1, str2, str3 };

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, пример исправил. Обратите внимание, что исходная строка одна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь нашел ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

С учетом того, что я имел возможность добавить свой разделитель (я выбрал '&'), правда не знаю, "нормально" ли это?

Что у меня получилось:

```
    string buf; // Строка используется в качестве буфера

    string stringFromUserFile = trip.GetStringFromUserFile(); // Получение строки, из которой нужно сформировать массив(с уже добавленным разделителем)

    stringstream iss(stringFromUserFile); // Вставляем полученную строку в поток(если правильно понял)

    vector<std::string> tokens; // Используем std::vector для хранения наших строк

    // Считываем строки из потока в buf, используя разделитель '&'
    while (getline(iss, buf, '&'))
    {
        tokens.push_back(buf); // Вставляем в конец tokens считанную строку
    }
```

Спасибо AR Hovsepyan и Harry за отклик.

Answer (score 0):

Наконец то выяснилось что вам нужно. Кажется это:

```
std::vector<std::string>
split(const std::string& s, char delim = '.')
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    size_t p = 0, sz = 0;
    while (sz != s.npos) {
        p = s.find_first_not_of(delim, sz);
        //если нужно пропустить пробелы
        p = s.find_first_not_of(' ', p);
        if (p == s.npos) break;
        sz = s.find(delim, p);
        //и если нужно одну точку пропустить
        if (delim == '.')
            sz = s.find(delim, sz + 1);
        v.push_back(s.substr(p, sz - p));            
    }
    return v;
}
```

Но еще не понятно,  точка после какой то цифры   учитывается или нет.

```
auto stringArray = split(str);
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); ++i)
   cout << stringArray[i] << '\n';
```